# processing Apache logs by date

Tags: unix

I have a simple unix routine that can look through all my Apache access logs for particular strings. That serves me well in checking for malicious mischief. 
I do this by just concatenating all the access logs, and then grepping the resulting file for the string.

I have several years worth of log files, one for each week. I'd like to analyze them by year, to make things go faster for recent searches.

Now, I could just specify a range, as in access_log.x.gz, where x goes from 1-52 for one year. BUT Apache rewrites all the filenames, such that the next to most recent one is access_log.0.gz, and the earliest one is access_log.x.pz, where x is a large number. **So the x range is not date-range-specific.**

How do I concatenate a files over a given creation date range? I'm reasonably competent at unix, but this is over my head. That is, for example, just concatenate all files for which the creation date is 2016.

Comment: Couldn't you do something like find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +365 -a \( \! -mtime +730 \) -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i 'foo' to for instance search all files older than 1 year but not older than 2 years?

Comment: I could use that, but I get a syntax error on " find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +365 -a ( \! -mtime +730 ) -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i 'foo' "

Comment: The brackets should have been escaped as well, by putting a bacsklash in front of each on of them (they were stripped from my comment; the one in front of the excalmation was left in place); in this case though you can leave the brackets out altogether, but the backslashed excl.mark is important (it reverses the operation of -a mtime).

Comment: play with it first by doing something like find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +356 -a  \! -mtime +730 -ls

Comment: Ah yes. That seems to work. I get files created in January 2016, which are the oldest files in my directory. Thank you! I think that will get me where I want to be.

Comment: You're welcome. Please note that mine was just an example, but you get the point.  If this was answered please flag it so. Thank you.